# WP on IIS: Logout on "Login Widget" hangs

Tags: wordpress, iis, authentication, logout, wp-admin

We’ve installed WordPress on a Windows Server (IIS).

Everything works fine except “Logout”. When you press “Logout” on the Admin-Panel it works fine but not when you press “Logout” on “Login Widget”. It just hangs instead of logging out and redirecting to a specific page.

The same “hanging” happens when I try to login through www.xyz.com/wp-admin/. Instead I login through www.xyz.com/wp-login.php and it works.
 
The same site on another “non-Windows” server works fine – logout and all.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Beni

Comment: Do you get an error message?  If it is an error 500 you may be able to look at the error logs.  The most likely culprit off the top of my mind, there is a bad redirect and it doesn't send the data the script is expecting.

Comment: This is the link that the User will be clicking

<a href="htt....xyz.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&amp;redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.xyz.com%2Fclient-login%2F&amp;_wpnonce=a4ff5a8c6e">Logout</a>

and this is the response after about 40-50 sec.

This site can’t be reached
xyz.com took too long to respond.

I activated the Admin-Bar and when i click the “Logout” there it works – this is the link

htt....xyz.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce=e634eb0c52

Which means that WordPress on IIS has a problem with redirect since on another server it works.

Any ideas?